# read files from directory that has running script rather than calling directory location from where the script was called, python

Tags: python, readfile, working-directory

suppose I have following

```
test/
    Main.py
test/one/
    One.py
    test1.txt
test/two/
    Two.py
    test2.txt
```

What I want to do is, run Main.py and call One.py and Two.py and want to read files.
Since directory containing One.py has one file test1.txt, I want to read that file
and directory containing Two.py has one file test2.txt

This can be done simply by

```
open("one/test1.txt", "r")
```

and
    open("two/test2.txt", "r")
in two files

Is there any other way to read files. This is simple case I took.

I am facing this problem. For this, I have created setting object and provide required location to that directory manually and passed this setting object to all class that needs location to read file

Is there different approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to know the directory of the running python file?

You can access the special variable `__file__` inside a Python program. It returns the path of the python file.

To open a named file in the running script's directory, use:

```
import os
f = open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "filename.txt"))
```